# Quit Avast on Mac Mojave

Tags: mac, avast, macos-mojave

Is there a way so that I can remove Avast from the status bar and stop it running in the background?

I can't seem to find a solution for this. I've tried stopping the processes on Activity Monitor and that doesn't work. There are a total of six processes running and stopping one simply causes it to reappear immediately.

Help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Uninstall it, or turn off Avast! from its own control panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same with most antivirus software... you can't disable it because its very job is to not be easily disabled.

You can either temporarily disable it from its own panel, or uninstall it from the App's File menu.

You must, of course, be an admin user to do this.

Full instructions at [Avast KB - Uninstalling Avast Security from Mac](https://support.avast.com/en-gb/article/Uninstall-Mac-Security)